# Allow migration to Code Golf

Tags: feature-request, migration

Recently I have found this question: [How can I simplify this code by using proper method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203806/how-can-i-simplify-this-code-by-using-proper-method). It asks to simplify the OP's code, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but is on topic for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com). I have also found other questions that shoulf been migrated to Code Golf. We should have an option to migrate to Code Golf "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network".

Comment: have you asked at Code Golf meta whether they would be OK with that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR** We don't offer this for a number of reasons, and your example question is not actually an example of a question that should be migrated there.

We don't have migration paths to every SE site for a reason—actually, several reasons:

1. It would be overwhelming.
2. There are many SE sites for which almost no appropriate questions are ever posted incorrectly on SO.
3. Many SO users are unfamiliar with the topics and rules of other SE sites, so many of those flags and close votes would be inappropriate.
4. And many more reasons.

Your proposal seems to embody reason #3 above, in that the example you give is not at all an appropriate question for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Code golf—the concept and, in large part, the site—is about writing the shortest code possible to complete a particular task, regardless of how pretty, ugly, intelligible, inscrutable, readable, or maintainable it is. It's not about *simplifying* code; it's about making it short, period. In other words, simplifying code and code golfing are not the same thing; you could even say they are [orthogonal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthogonal) to each other.

In short, there's no need for this migration path.

Comment: I completely agree. *simplifying* code and *code golf* are often times completely at odds at each other. Code Review might be more appropriate if any migration is really needed, but SO itself should also be fine for many such requests.

Answer (score 12):

## Simplifying code has almost nothing to do with code golf

In the former, you're trying to write good maintainable code. This means using proper formatting, descriptive variable names, good practices, etc. Meanwhile, the only objective in code golf is to write the shortest possible program to solve a problem at all costs.

For example, here's a simple "Hello world!" program in C++:

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

And here's a code golf solution that does the same thing:

```
“3ḅaė;œ»
```

([Source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66399))

The question you linked to also isn't a challenge or is related to programming puzzles in any way.